# Connecting multiple .sks files to multiple objective c classes

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am currently building a sprite kit game in Objective C and am having some trouble getting .sks files attached to subclasses I have created. I am trying to make a .sks file for each level (attaching multiple .sks files to a single "gamePlay" class) as well as have another .sks file attached to a separate "mainMenu" class for the home screen. Does anyone know how to link multiple .sks files to multiple classes?

I have looked at the WWDC 2014 session and have been able to change single .sks files to work with a single subclass, but I haven't been able to do it for many classes and many .sks files.

All help is appreciated.